# javascript/typescript - accessing values in an object array 2 levels down

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Lots of questions on this but I am having trouble finding a solution.

I have an typescript interface called ClientDetails:

```
interface ClientDetails {

        clientId: number;
        clientNo: number;
        ...

        jobs: Job[];
 }
```

I have created a variable in the class like so:

```
client: ClientDetails;
```

So "client" has values for clientId, ClientNo and jobs[].

Each job is structured as an interface "Job"

```
    interface Job {
        id: number;
        agentJobNo: number;
        jobNo: number;
        jobType: string;
        jobVisits: Visit[]
        numberOfVisits: number;
        status: string;
    }
```

and each job has an array called jobVisits that is set to the interface "Visit":

```
    interface Visit {
        jobVisitId: number;
        dateCreated: string;
        visitDate: string;
        startTime: string;
        endTime: string;
    }
```

I wanted to obtain all the jobVisits in a specific job as I had the job.id number.

I used the following code and was able to obtain the correct job:

```
 let test3 = this.client.jobs.filter(f => f.id === jobId);
```

What I want is the array of jobVisits in the job however it seems everything I try and do to obtain this sub array is met with an error...

Given this structure Client.Jobs and an id how can I return the array of jobVisits?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your code with map

```
let test3 = this.client.jobs.filter(f => f.id === jobId);

if(test3 && test3.length > 0){
var visits =  test3.map((j)=>{
                              return j.jobVisits;
                         });
}
```